# Test email sending in Batch class

Tags: unit-test, email, batch, code-coverage

I have created a batch that sends in email anytime the status of an article is updated.
I am trying to write a test class for the batch but I only manage to cover 45% of the class.
I struggle to cover the execute method from the batch where I send the email.
[image]

Could someone help?
Thanks

Batch class:

```
global class BatchArticleEmail implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject> {

global string query;

// To schedule batch 
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    Id batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(this);
}

// Constructor to query articles
global BatchArticleEmail() {
    
    query = 'Select Id, KnowledgeArticleId, Known_Error_Status__c, Title FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE PublishStatus=\'Online\'' + 
            'AND LastModifiedDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:1';  
    System.debug('query BatchArticleEmail ' +query);
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
     return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Knowledge__kav> scope) {
    System.debug('#### Scope BatchArticleEmail ' + scope.size());
    
    Set<Id> kavIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Knowledge__kav kv : scope) {
        kavIds.add(kv.KnowledgeArticleId);
    }
    System.debug('BatchArticleEmail kavList KnowledgeArticleId ' +kavIds);
    
    Map<Id, Known_Error_Subscription__c> kesMap = new Map<Id, Known_Error_Subscription__c>(
        [SELECT KnowledgeKA__c, Article_Status__c, Article_Title__c, Contact__c, 
          Contact__r.AccountId FROM Known_Error_Subscription__c WHERE KnowledgeKA__c IN :kavIds]);
    System.debug('BatchArticleEmail Known_Error_Subscription__c Map ' +kesMap);
    
    //Send Email to subscriber when subscription (Article Status) != Known Error Status
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Id,HTMLValue, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =:'Smart_Community_Known_Error_Status_Update'];
    
    for(Known_Error_Subscription__c kes : kesMap.Values()) {
        for(Knowledge__kav kav : scope) {
            if(kes.Article_Status__c != kav.Known_Error_Status__c) {
                
                //Send email to subscriber
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTargetObjectId(kes.Contact__c);
                System.debug('###  mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId()) ' +  UserInfo.getUserId());            
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(template.Id, kes.Contact__c, kes.Id);            
                String[] sendingTo = new String[]{kes.Contact__c};
                mail.setToAddresses(sendingTo);
                mail.setSubject(template.Subject);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                mail.setHtmlBody(email.getHtmlBody());
                allmsg.add(mail);  
            }   
        }
    }
    //Reset Article Status in Subscription
    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] results = Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg, false);
    for(Messaging.SendEmailResult res : results) {
        System.debug('Email result: ' + res.isSuccess());
        if(res.IsSuccess()) {
            for (Knowledge__kav kav : scope) {
                for(Known_Error_Subscription__c kes : kesMap.Values()) {
                    kes.Article_Title__c = kav.Title;
                    kes.Article_Status__c = kav.Known_Error_Status__c;
                    System.debug('***Article_Status__c ' + kes.Article_Status__c);
                }
            }
            update  kesMap.Values();
        }
        else if(!res.IsSuccess())
        System.debug('Error: ' +  res.getErrors());
    } 
    
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) {
    
}

}
```

Test class

```
@isTest
public class BatchArticleTest {

@testSetup
static void setup() {
    Account acct = new Account(Name = 'test Account');
    insert acct;
    
    Case c = new Case(Status = 'New', AccountId = acct.Id, Type = 'Feature');
    insert c;
    
    Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'test contact');
    insert con;
    
    //Create article
    Knowledge__kav kav = new Knowledge__kav(Title = 'test', UrlName = 'test', Related_Problem__c = c.Id, Affecting__c = 'test',
                                            Known_Error_Status__c = 'Fixed');                                        
    insert kav;
    
    Known_Error_Subscription__c kes = new Known_Error_Subscription__c(Contact__c = con.Id, KnowledgeKA__c = kav.KnowledgeArticleId,
                                                                      Article_Status__c = 'In Review', 
                                                                      Article_Title__c = kav.Title);
    insert kes;
             
}
// test BatchArticleEmail
@isTest static void test() {
    List<Knowledge__kav> kavList = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Title = 'test'];
    List<Knowledge__kav> kavToUpdate = new List<Knowledge__kav>();
    for(knowledge__kav kv : kavList) {
        kv.Known_Error_Status__c = 'No Fix';
        kavToUpdate.add(kv);
    }
    update kavToUpdate;
    System.debug('kavToUpdate ' +kavToUpdate);
             
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
        System.debug('###  mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId()) ' +  UserInfo.getUserId());            
        String[] sendingTo = new String[]{'test@gmail.com'};
        mail.setToAddresses(sendingTo);
        mail.setSubject('Subject');
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mail.setHtmlBody('body');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.Email> {mail});
        
        Test.startTest();
        BatchArticleEmail batchEmail = new BatchArticleEmail();
        Database.QueryLocator ql = batchEmail.start(null);
        batchEmail.execute(null,kavList);
        batchEmail.Finish(null);
        //Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(batchEmail);
        Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: Not an answer at all, but please don't use global unless absolutely essential (I.e. the symbol needs to be visible across a namespace boundary).

Comment: Does kesMap have any values?

Comment: Hello, yes kesMap does have a value